# Unable to insert record into mongodb using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save record into mongodb using `node.js` and for that purpose I am using `mongoose` driver but here I am unable to insert record into mongodb. I am explaining my code below.

**mongo.util.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
const config = require('../../config/settings');

const mongooseInstance = new mongoose();
const url = `mongodb://${config.MONGO_USER}:${config.MONGO_PWD}@${config.MONGO_URL}/${config.MONGO_DB}`;
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
};

/*
 1- Connect to mongo server
*/

mongooseInstance.connect(url, options, (err) => {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('Mongodb connection successed');
    } else {
        console.log('Error in DB connection:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, true));
    }
})

module.exports = mongooseInstance;
```

This file is my connection file where I can connect to my local `mongodb`. This file has included into mt `app.js` file and I am getting the message as `Mongodb connection successed`.

**users.model.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    mobile: { type: String},
    password: { type: String},
    email: { type: String},
    city: { type: String}
}, {
    timestamps: {
        CreatedAt: 'CreatedAt',
        UpdatedAt: 'UpdatedAt'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('customers', User);
```

The above file is my schema file where I am trying to design schema for `customer` collection.

**users.service.js:**

```
const _ = require('lodash'),
      axios = require('axios'),
      model = require('../model/users.model');

async registerUser(req) {

        try{

            const data = req.body;
            console.log('data', data);

            const user = await model.create(data);

            if (!user) {
                return {
                    data: user,
                    error: true,
                    msg: 'User Registeration failed'
                }
            }else {
                return {
                    data: user,
                    error: false,
                    msg: 'User Registered successfully'
                }
            }
        }catch(error) {
            console.log('Error in registerUser service::', error);
        }
    }
```

Here I trying to insert the record but when this function is called no record is inserting into mongodb even no customer collection is there. Here I need to insert record using this `mongoose` driver.

Comment: Can you  post your codes in the " model.create(data)" function so that people can have more information ?

Comment: I think `create` is inbuilt method of mongoose to insert record into database.

Comment: Can you try once with "model.save(data)"

Comment: @Jitendra: Got error as `model.save is not a function`.

Comment: create object out of User model || var user = new model(req.body) || then call user.save(function(){})

Comment: I have tried this approach but still same issue.

Comment: Why are you creating a new mongoose object (`const mongooseInstance = new mongoose();`). Try updating the import as => `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` and use this `mongoose` object for connection(`mongoose.connect(url, options, (err)... `).

Comment: @Vishnu: Thanks for catching the issue point. It resolved my issue today.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

Step 1: create object out of User model

`var user = new model(req.body)`

Step 2: then call

```
user.save(function(){})
```